# Is Traffic Control (tc) broken in Fedora 17?

Tags: networking, fedora, tc

After upgrading from Fedora 16 to Fedora 17, Traffic Control no longer seems to work.

Running `# tc qdisc show` will output:

`qdisc pfifo_fast 0: dev eth0 root refcnt 2 bands 3 priopmap  1 2 2 2 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1`

However, if I run `# tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 100ms` or similar commands such as `# tc ... loss 2%` or `# tc ... corrupt 3%` I get the following:

**`RNETLINK answers: No such file or directory`**

Downgrading back to Fedora 16 allows me to use Traffic Control without this problem, so I'm convinced it's not a hardware issue.

This question is similar to https://serverfault.com/questions/318926/tc-netem-possibly-missing but I believe the right components were installed by checking `# yum provides */tc` and ascertaining that tc is from the package `iproute`, whose latest installation I have.

Is `netem` part of another package I must also install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fedora 17 they moved a lot of unused (in common usage I guess) modules for the kernel into the package *kernel-modules-extra*.

Installing this package will fix the problem.

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/398964/112950